# Display ordinal data in a circular manner

Tags: plotting, graphics

**1. Problem statement**

I want to display "categories" (f.e. the yearly winners of a football league) in a circular manner -  a rounded version of `OrdinalScale` in a certain sense.

**2. Toy data**

```
data = {
   {"Chelsea", {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}},
   {"Arsenal", {0, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}},
   {"City", {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.6}}} /. 0 :> Missing[];
```

**3. My solution**

```
ListPolarPlot[data[[All, 2]],
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[0.02],
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1 ;; 3]], data[[All, 1]], LegendMarkerSize -> 15],
 PlotRangePadding -> 0.2,
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
 PolarAxes -> Automatic,
 PolarGridLines -> {Table[i, {i, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/12}], {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0}},
 PolarTicks -> {{{Pi/2, 2003}, {2 Pi, 2000}, {Pi, 2006}, {3 Pi/2, 2009}}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

**4. Questions**

1. Is it possible to display the plot clockwise? 2000 at noon and then moving right?
2. If a team wins several years in a row (f.e. Arsenal between 2001 and 2004),
   I would like to emphasize this by coloring the arc segments between the points (orange in this case).
3. How can I change the color of the outermost circle (now black) to gray?

`ListPolarPlot` is the solution I found. Please feel free to propose other circle-like display styles.

**5. Acceptance**

I accepted Syed's answer, because it's easy to add the markers. For example:

```
data = {
   {"Chelsea", {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}},
   {"Arsenal", {0, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}},
   {"City", {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.6}}};

RadialAxisPlot[data[[All, 2]],
 AxesOrigin -> {0, -1},
 Ticks -> Automatic,
 AxesLabel -> Range[2000, 2012],
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.05},
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Automatic, data[[All, 1]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use v12.2 on Win7-x64 and the graphics rendering was sub-optimal for my version so I switched to the free cloud account.

```
$Version
data = {{"Chelsea", {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0}}, {"Arsenal", {0, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}}, {"City", {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.6}}};
```

> 13.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)

```
RadialAxisPlot[data[[All, 2]], AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}, 
 Ticks -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> Range[2000, 2012]
 ,PlotLegends->SwatchLegend[Automatic, data[[All,1]]]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Playing with the options `Axes`, `Ticks` and  `AxesOrigin` we can (1) eliminate the visual ambiguity regarding which year the zeros at the origin belong to, and (2) to get a quick/dirty compromise between linear/ordinal and cyclical views of *time* (this is accomplished by simply appending and prepending known histories with `Nulls` :))

```
radialorigin = .5;

RadialAxisPlot[
 Join[{Null, Null}, #, {Null}] & /@ AssociationThread @@ Transpose[data],
 AxesOrigin -> {{-Pi, -1}, radialorigin},
 Ticks -> {1 -> Range[0, 1., .2]},
 Axes -> 
   {2 | 3 + Max@Map[Length]@data[[All, 2]] -> False, _ -> Automatic},
 AxesLabel -> Join[{"", ""}, Range[2000, 2012]],
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.05},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 GridLines -> Range[radialorigin + .1, 1.2, .1]]
```

[image]

An alternative visualization is using [`ParallelAxisPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelAxisPlot.html)

```
ParallelAxisPlot[data, 
  AxesStyle -> 
   {1 -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Gray],
    _ -> Directive[ Gray, FontOpacity -> 0]}, 
  AxesLabel -> Range[2000, 2012], 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.05}, 
  PlotLegends -> data[[All, 1]], 
  ImageSize -> 1 -> 400] /. 
 l_Line :> {l, 
   Dynamic @ First @
     ListLinePlot[l[[1]], PlotHighlighting -> None, 
      PlotStyle -> CurrentValue["Color"], Filling -> Bottom]}
```

[image]